# How to return the iPhone keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, keyboard

The storyboard scene is like this:

`UITableViewController` with a `UITableView` with a custom prototype `UITableViewCell`: `AddInfoCell`.

I placed a editable `UITextView` in the `AddInfoCell`.

To return a keyboard, I use to put the following code in the `UIViewController` class and connect it to the `UITextView` with option `DidEndOnExit`:

```
- (IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

But I can't find a suitable place for this code now as the `UITextView` is in the `AddInfoCell` class.

It's not connectable with the `UITextView` from the `TableViewController` class or the `AddInfoCell` class.

I also tried to create a `TextViewController` class for the `UITextView` and place the `textFieldReturn` code there but still I cannot connect it in the storyboard..

So any suggestions on how to return the keyboard in this case?

This is where `AddInfoCell is created:

```
- (AddInfoCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"AddInfoCell";

AddInfoCell *addInfoCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (addInfoCell == nil) {
    addInfoCell = [[AddInfoCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
return addInfoCell;

}
```

Comment: set the textfield delegate to your viewcontroller class. the same method will work.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit closer?

Comment: when ur creating the object of custom cell, say for 

eg. AddInfoCell *cell, thn set cell.delegate = self. And u can call ur textfield delegates in ur view controller itself.

Comment: It's created in cellForRowAtIndexPath but I cannot write addInfoCell.delegate = self in here it's not appearing as an option when I start writing.. But it sounds a lot more simple than the other answer if you can show an example and describe it as another answer?

Comment: y cant u set the delegate for cell??
Im sry i dnt have the sample code now. i will get it to u tom maybe.

Comment: I added the code for the cell in my question. If I write addInfoCell.delegate = self; in there somewhere then no property for delegate is found. I hope you can show me tomorrow!

Comment: that prob is simple, in ur viewcontroller interface just add UITextFieldDelegate. 

@interface AddCellViewControler :UITableViewController < UITextFieldDelegate > 

set the delegate and try calling the textfield delegate methods..

Comment: addInfoCell.delegate = self;



- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{ 
} 

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{ 
[textField resignFirstResponder]; 

}

i hope this will suffice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

addInfoCell.cellTextView.delegate = self;

Answer (score 2):

Use `UITextViewDelegate` delegate.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Also add this method:

```
 -(BOOL)textViewShouldReturn:(UITextView *)textView {
   [textView resignFirstResponder];
   return YES;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but where should I add this code? Tried it everywhere but it made no difference.. Can you explain the procedure to make this work?

Comment: Add this where your UITextView is. Also bind its delegate.

Comment: Meaning in the UITableViewCell class I suppose. Thanks a lot so far but I need to ask : how to bind its delegate?

Comment: If UITextView in xib then right click and there is delegate which u drag to fileowner. Now add .h file @interface viewController :UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>